# What's wrong with my In Place Heap Sorting code

Tags: java, sorting, heap, heapsort

I'm working on a school assignment and the assignment was to make a heap sorting (In Place) program. Now the program works perfectly fine for arrays with under +- 20 elements, above that it occasionally messes up, however I can't seem to find what's wrong.

```
/**
 * swaps two elements in an array
 *
 * @param a array
 * @param i position of element to swap in a
 * @param j position of element to swap in a
 */
public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}

/**
 * restores the heap property in a heap represented as an array
 * 4 5 0
 * <p>
 * restoreHeap([4, 5, 0], 0, 3)
 * biggest = 1
 *
 * @param heap  array representation of a heap,
 *              which might be invalidated
 * @param root  index of the root of the heap,
 *              which might be a subtree of the overall heap
 * @param range index of the last element in the heap,
 *              array elements with an index > range are not part of the heap
 *              <p>
 *              when the heap property is invalid at root,
 *              the method fixes the heap first locally before fixing the affected subtree
 */
public static void restoreHeap(int[] heap, int root, int range) {
    final int left = root * 2 + 1;
    final int right = root * 2 + 2;
    final int size = root + range;
    int biggest = root;
    if (left < size && heap[left] > heap[biggest]) {
        biggest = left;
    }
    if (right < size && heap[right] > heap[biggest]) {
            biggest = right;
    }

    if (biggest != root) {
        swap(heap, biggest, root);
        restoreHeap(heap, biggest, range - (biggest - root));
    }
}


/**
 * turns an array of integers into a heap
 * <p>
 * this is an in-place algorithm, the heap is built in the array itself
 * 1 2 4 5 9 3
 *
 * @param array of integer numbers,
 *              on return, this array represents a valid heap
 */
public static void buildHeap(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int temp = i;
        while (array[temp / 2] < array[temp]) {
            swap(array, temp / 2, temp);
            temp /= 2;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * sorts an array of integer numbers
 * <p>
 * this is an in-place algorithm, the heap is built in the array itself
 *
 * @param array of elements, on return, this array represents a valid heap
 */
public static void inPlaceHeapSort(int[] array) {
    buildHeap(array);
    int arrSize = array.length;
    while (arrSize > 1) {
        swap(array, arrSize - 1, 0);
        arrSize--;
        restoreHeap(array, 0, arrSize);
    }
}
```

The skeleton for the methods was already there so if you're asking why certain parameters are even there, it's because it was compulsory.

Comment: Weird. The question's code is deleted for "privacy reasons" and it has 3 upvotes?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Self-vandalism. Please roll back such instances when encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem's to be indexing, the indexing for left and right seems to be wrong

`final int left = root * 2 + 1;
 final int right = root * 2 + 2;`

here you should change the code to

`final int left = root * 2;
final int right = root * 2 + 1;`

Also remember that you have to index the array from 1, instead of 0.

Comment: For 0-based arrays such as this assignment I believe my indexing is correct, yes I would rather have an array indexed from 1 but that would require for me to create a new array which defeats the purpose of the assignment. Also if my indexing were actually incorrect I don't think it'd work in any of the cases but it just doesn't work when the array size goes over approximately 20, right?

Comment: The indexing using 0 is incorrect because when you try to find the parent by dividing by 2 you would get the wrong parent, lets consider the example of 6 , when we divide it by 2 we get 3 as the parent but according to the logic its parent should be 2(because right = root * 2 + 2 ==> right = (2 * 2) + 2).

Comment: To do inplace sorting you can always consider the index to be starting from 1, and according to logic do "i+1" and "i-1" when required, that would solve the problem